# JSON.NET not utilizing TypeConverter for Dictionary key

Tags: c#, json, json.net, typeconverter

I am attempting to use [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize/deserialize a `SortedDictionary<Time, T>`, where `Time` is a custom class in my project, and `T` is some type that need not be included here.

Serialization works perfectly. Take this dictionary, for example:

```
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<Time, T> {
  [Time.Parse("7:00AM")] = ...,
  [Time.Parse("8:00AM")] = ...,
  [Time.Parse("9:00AM")] = ...
};
```

(`Time.Parse()` is a simple method that constructs `Time` objects from a string input.) Now, if I run `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented)`, I get something like this:

```
{
  "7:00AM": ...,
  "8:00AM": ...,
  "9:00AM": ...
}
```

This is because the `Time` class overrides the `ToString()` method, so the dictionary keys can easily be converted to strings.

Unfortunately, deserialization fails here. Given the output of the last example, running `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SortedDictionary<Time, T>>(previousOutput)` produces an exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
>
> Could not convert string '7:00AM' to dictionary key type '[...].Time'. Create a TypeConverter to convert from the string to the key type object. [...]

Okay, that makes sense. After all, without *some* kind of converter, there is no way for JSON.NET to know how to handle this. However, my `Time` class already has a `Parse(string)` method. So, I created a `TypeConverter` called `TimeConverter` that utilizes it, like so:

```
public class TimeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) && base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return value is string s ? Time.Parse(s) : base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string) && value is Time t
        ? t.ToString()
        : base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

I then added a `TypeConverter` attribute to the `Time` class declaration:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TimeConverter))]
public class Time : IComparable<Time>
{
   ...
}
```

However, this did not work. The exact same error is still thrown. Additionally, I tried placing breakpoints in the `TimeConverter` methods, but they were never triggered. JSON.NET seems to be completely ignoring my converter. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was a combination of two different issues:

1. As explained in @dbc's answer, I was using `&&` instead of `||` in `TimeConverter.CanConvertFrom()`.
2. I was using version 9 of Json.NET, but *in .NET Core*, `TypeConverter` support was not implemented until version 10.

Using `||` and upgrading to Json.NET 12 solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify [`TimeConverter.CanConvertFrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.canconvertfrom?view=net-5.0#System_ComponentModel_TypeConverter_CanConvertFrom_System_ComponentModel_ITypeDescriptorContext_System_Type_) to return true if the incoming type is `typeof(string)` **or** the base class can convert the type:

```
public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
{
    return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
}
```

As can be seen from the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/componentmodel/TypeConverter.cs,72), the base class's `CanConvertFrom()` only returns `true` when the incoming type is `typeof(InstanceDescriptor)`.  Thus your `CanConvertFrom()` return false when passed `typeof(string)` and the conversion methods never got called.

A demo of the original problem using a mockup for `Time` class can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NicoO1).

A demo of the fixed, working `TypeConverter` can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/stER2j).

Note however that, if you are using .NET Core, support for type converters was only added as of [Json.NET 10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1).  If you are targeting netstandard1.0+ or .NET Core and are using an earlier version Json.NET you will need to upgrade.  See *[Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489/3744182)* for details.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I've changed my code, but for some reason it still doesn't work. `CanConvertFrom()` never even seems to be called. However, your fiddle does seem to work, so I'm not sure what I'm doing differently. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JacobLockard - Then please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].  I had to create a mockup for `Time` and make a guess as to the `T` type in the dictionary.  You're more likely to get useful debugging help if we can reproduce your problem.  See: [ask].   I initially had to create my own [MCVE] for your problem here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NicoO1

Comment: @JacobLockard - Does your actual `Time` class also implement `IConvertible`?  If so, maybe see [Newtonsoft.Json - DeserializeObject throws when deserializing custom type: Error converting value “somestring” to type CustomType](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64972694/3744182).

Comment: Well, after an example on DotNetFiddle worked, I finally decided to just try updating my version of Newtonsoft.Json. Sure enough, upgrading from 9.* to 12.* solved the issue! Thanks for your help! What is the recommended action in this case? Should I create a new answer with what I did and mark it as the accepted one, or should I just leave the question be?

Comment: @JacobLockard - Even if you update from Json.NET 9 to 12, I don't think your converter will work unless you make `CanConvertFrom()` return true.  My failing fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/NicoO1 uses Json.NET 12.  But it's quite possible you would need to do both if you are working in .Net Core, as Json.NET did not support type converters **in .Net Core** until [release 10](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1).

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant. After implementing your changes *and* updating it works. Thus my confusion: your answer helped but didn't exactly solve the problem (and thus, is not exactly the "Accepted Answer"). How should I handle this? Oh, and I was using .NetStandard 2.1.